# Youtube iframe fails with chrome, works with IE

Tags: youtube-api

I have made a simple test page that fails with chrome, but works with IE.
It is at:
http://www.rateforsuccess.com/test2.aspx

If you use IE, you will see that the video plays for about a second, and then you can do a seek, (with the SEEK button) and it will seek 100 seconds into the video, and play for about 7 seconds.  You will see and hear a woman talking.

But in chrome, this fails multiple ways. Sometimes clicking the SEEK button does not work the first time but works the second time. Sometimes the clip will play, but without any visuals - you just hear the audio.
Its a simple page, so I do not understand this.

There is a another odd thing, sometimes if you clear the cache and then access the page,  you get the error, but if you don't clear the cache, eventually it works (sometimes).
Any help is appreciated.